# SQL casting seconds in time stamp to an integer

Tags: sql, r, casting, timestamp

I'm trying to cast the seconds from a time stamp variable in a data set to an integer. So far I've gotten it down to the substring where it just outputs the seconds of a time stamp but for whatever reason, I can't get rid of the letter 'Z' at the end no matter what index I reference when trying to substring so that I can cast the value to an integer. I've included screenshots of my data and my attempt of substringing the value below.

[image: Time Column]

[image: Output]

This is my output so far, can anyone help?

Comment: use text instead of screenshot

Comment: Here's the text of my code:   sqldf("select substring(time, 17, LENGTH(time)-1)
from mydata 
limit 10;")

Comment: scto, please (1) don't post images of code or data, it presumes that we will have the time and care to transcribe the data you already have textually in your R console, in R-friendly data formats, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/); and (2) comments can easily be missed by readers or hidden (when many) by the Stack interface. If you have something to add to the question, then [edit] it and keep the question itself self-contained without comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fake data

```r
mydata <- data.frame(time = "2018-09-07T01:07:14.599Z")
```

> **Edit**: I hadn't noticed that `substring` is an alias for `substr`, I've changed the text here to reflect that.

Both `substr` and the alias `substring` have as the last argument the *length* of the returned string. From the [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

> The substr(X,Y,Z) function returns a substring of input string X that begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long. ...

This is in contrast with some (non-sqlite) substring-like implementations that use `start` and `end`, for which your code would work.

```r
sqldf::sqldf("select substr(time, 18, length(time)-18) from mydata")
#   substr(time, 18, length(time)-18)
# 1                            14.599
```

I don't know why you are introducing `sqldf` into this, though: while it is good, it will almost certainly be far faster to do this in R via a few different methods:

```r
### notice that this is start,end not start,length
substr(mydata$time, 18, nchar(mydata$time)-1)
# [1] "14.599"

format(as.POSIXct(mydata$time, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ"), format = "%OS3")
# [1] "14.598"             # the 598-vs-599 thing is due to floating-point IEEE-754

as.POSIXlt(mydata$time, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")$sec
# [1] 14.599               # numeric, not string
```

Comment: SQLite does support `substring` as an alias for `substr` since SQLite version 3.34.0. See https://sqlite.org/draft/releaselog/3_34_0.html   The most recent version of RSQLite on CRAN is 2.2.5 and it contains SQLite 3.35.2 so it does contain `substring`.